# Append Style to DOM not Replacing Existing

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dom-events

How can I **append** style element to DOM without eliminating existing style on the item (eg color, text-align, etc)?

The event calls the function, but the problem is 'Style' gets completely replaced with the single item instead.

I have simple code triggered on the event:

```
function changeback(onoff) {
   if(onoff) {
      document.getElementById("field1").style.background="#fff";
   } else            
      document.getElementById("field1").style.background="#000";
}
```

Comment: That code is not the issue. Unless you are saying the other background properties are being overwritten, that code should NOT affect other properties of the Element's `style` object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which browser are you using? In Chrome, this works for me:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
  .test { background: #ff0000; font-family: "Verdana"; }
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function changeback(onoff)
  {
    if(onoff){
      document.getElementById("field1").style.background="#0f0";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("field1").style.background="#000";
    }
  }
 </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
   <h1>Test</h1> 
   <p id="field1" onclick="changeback(true);" class="test">This is a test</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

When I click on the text, the background color changes, but the rest of the style (in this case, the font) stays the same.

Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to append to existing Style, not replace. Try adding a style to field1 then appending the color with javascript.

Comment: @Codex73: Your comment makes no sense. The answer just changes the background color and leaves the rest of the style settings alone. What specifically is your problem? Which part of the style gets reset?

Comment: Yes. Your completely right, minor code problem on my end. Thanks for your help, it works.

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you can do it :

```
var elem = document.getElementById('YOUR ELEMENT ID');
elem.style.setProperty('border','1px solid black','');
```

`elem.style` is an object implementing the [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration) interface which supports a `setProperty` function. If you check the style property in Firebug now, you will notice addition of the border property within the style attribute of the element.

Comment: I'm trying to append to existing Style, not replace. Try adding a style to field1 then appending the color with javascript. It didn't do the trick.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/KAjf2/

The element has a style of "color:red" already to it. I append a "border" to the existing Style. Working in FF 3.5,Chrome

Comment: @Codex73 `style.setProperty()` does not replace existing properties, it adds a new property.